# How to use COUNT option with Redis Repositories (GeoOperations)

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-redis

I'm using Spring Data Redis with Geospatial Index. Every query method work. I would like to use the COUNT option, but I didn't find any more complex example in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.indexes.geospatial). Does anyone knows how to use the COUNT option at this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Pageable` to limit results. Staying on page 0 with e.g. `Pageable.of(0, 10)` limits the results to 10. However the number of items per page is not passed on to the `COUNT` option of the `GEORADIUS` command.
I've opened [DATAREDIS-666](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-666) for this.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophStrobl, I will follow the task. I hope to see this correction in the next version.